# deleting than saving bulk data simultaneously in single transaction issue

Tags: hibernate, transactions

I have two list. First list contains data which is to be saved and second list contains data which is to be deleted. I need to perform bulk deletion than i need to save bulk insertion in single transaction. Following is the code that i used to perform these operation :

```
public void bulkSaveDeleteOperation(final List<Person> personList, 
        final List<Person> duplicatePersonList) {
    Session session = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    try {
        //delete operation
        if (duplicatePersonList != null) {
            Integer deleteCounter = 0;
            for (Person cp : duplicatePersonList) {
                session.delete(cp);
                deleteCounter++;
                if (deleteCounter % 20 == 0) {
                    session.flush();
                    session.clear();
                }
            }
        }
        //save operation
        if (personList != null) {
            Integer saveCounter = 0;
            for (Person cp : personList) {
                session.saveOrUpdate(cp);
                saveCounter++;
                if (saveCounter % 20 == 0) {
                    session.flush();
                    session.clear();
                }
            }
        }
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Now the problem is, data from list which is to be saved i.e. (personList) are inserted to database successfully in final commit but data from list which is to be deleted i.e. (duplicatePersonList) are not deleted. Both deletion and insertion operation hits same table in database. so, what is wrong going here, i couldn't figure out.